# Is every subring of a principal ideal ring also a principal ideal ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For the normal definition of a PIR (every ideal is principal in the ring), is every subring also a PIR?

I can't seem to think of a counterexample.

Comment: $\mathbb Z[X]\subset\mathbb Q[X]$

Comment: @ArnaudD. is a PID equivalent to a PIR (just a difference of notation?) It may be the way I'm learning it in my class that is different

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard so does this not hold? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ring_of_Integers_is_Principal_Ideal_Domain

Comment: @tdashrom - $\mathbb Z$ is a PID but $\mathbb Z[X]$ is not.

Comment: The `Domain` part in PID means that there are no zero divisors. `PID` is `PIR + Domain`.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments at the other question (but not in any answers I've seen so far, bafflingly) is that if you accept fields as PIDS (which I think should be reasonable) then every integral domain is a subring of a PID... so obviously they can't all be PIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly $\Bbb C[X]$ is a PID. But $\Bbb C$ contains subrings
isomorphic to $\Bbb Q[Y_1,Y_2]$ which have non-principal ideals.